# Font dispose - How to: Implement the Dispose Finalize Pattern (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, itext

First thing my program only use 3 to 5 fonts and only when I create a PDF.

I think there's no need to Dispose the Fonts objects from the point of view of resources but for learning and create a good habit it will be good.

I try to do

```vb
If myFont1 IsNot Nothing Then
    myFont1.Dispose()
End If
```

or

```vb
If myFont1 IsNot Nothing Then
    myFont1.IDisposable.Dispose()
End If
```

And I get the "Dispose or IDisposable is not a member of Font"

To implement the Dispose Option I really need to do ALL this work?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9bwddyx(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: `IDisposable ` is an interface.  Something like Bitmap or Font which implements it will be required to have a `Dispose` method.  Where are you trying to do this, a form or a class?

Comment: Only on a Windows Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like you already suggested:

```
If myFont1 IsNot Nothing Then
    myFont1.Dispose()
End If
```

since `Font` type does implement `IDisposable` interface as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Your answer refers the `System.Drawing` font class. But reading the tag [tag:itext] of the OP's question, most likely the OP means the iTextSharp font class.

Comment: @mkl Right!! Maybe that's the reason, iText font is not disposable?

Comment: @fedeteka indeed, it is not, cf. the source: [Font.cs](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/develop/src/core/iTextSharp/text/Font.cs).